# Word press form data submit to another database

Tags: database, wordpress

I have a registration form on my WordPress website, I need to save that information into another server database, Is it possible? I am new in WordPress.
Please note the other database is not wordpress database.
I need to collect the data from wordpress forms and save it to another database in another server.

Comment: The other database is also a WordPress database?

Comment: @Zecka, No its in another application. We have fixed the issue by creating custom form